# Simple change causes JS to break

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have the following JS to catch any users who dont use my autocomplete for addresses.

```
function check() {
let latitude = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
if (latitude) {
    window.prompt("It passed", "");

  } else {

 let term = $("#getaddy").val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+encodeURIComponent(term) +'&key=API_KEY',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.status === 'OK') {
            let lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            let lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

            window.prompt("should show", "");

        }
    },
    error: function(msg) {

    }
});

    window.prompt("it failed", "");
    return true;
}
}
```

Right now if there is no latitude, it shows the window prompt it failed and then the window prompt should show. However, if I delete the window prompt it failed, the should show doesn't appear. Why is this?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to edit out your key there, it looks like it should probably be private

Comment: Sounds like `data.status` isn't `OK`, `console.log` it around there

Comment: ... or the request fails with an error and you don't notice it as the error handler is empty.

Comment: OP, I edited the key out on your behalf. People could rack up charges on your account, or overload your free quota, by using your key. If you care about it at all, you will also follow the procedure outlined at [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or) and raise a flag to have the key redacted from the revision history.

Comment: Put some more diagnostics. What is `data` at the start of the callback? (you only have some output when status is okay, which severely restricts your debugging capabilities). Also your error handler is empty, which again says "i don't care if an error occured, not my problem". Output everything, then when you have the data on what is actually happening, you might know more. (We also can't help you until you provide such feedback, but I suspect you will know the answer even without our help if you just log all data at all possible branches.)

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks so much!